# PEP 484 Circumventing 'Any' matching to all types

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting

```
class LibraryClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.y = 34

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

class MyClass:
    pass

myObj = MyClass()
libraryObj = LibraryClass()

def myFunc(x: MyClass):
    print("Got it")

myFunc(myObj) #Rightly UnFlagged
myFunc(34) #Rightly Flagged
myFunc(libraryObj.y) #Rightly Flagged
myFunc(libraryObj.x) #Wrongly Unflagged. The default return type is Any
```

In the code above, the user function myFunc is supposed to only accept parameter x of type MyClass. However, the 'Any' type is matched as well (in the final line) because of how the 'Any' type is defined in PEP 484. Is there a way to circumvent this?

I understand that it is by design; 'Any' is supposed to match any signature; this makes sense if the 'Any' was explicitly defined type, however, in the case such as the above example where 'Any' is coming from a library object because  it is the default return type of functions, it doesn't make sense to me.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure which type checker you're using, but `myFunc(libraryObj.y)` isn't flagged by `mypy==0.641`.  If you're ok with mypy-specific features, I believe `mypy --disallow-any-expr ...` has the behaviour you desire

Comment: I am using pyCharm. Yeah, it is quite intelligent actually and would flag libraryObj.x too if the function definition simply had return 34, for example. 
However, for a particular library function I am using, it doesn't flag because the function is more complicated and it cannot infer the return type, so falls back to Any.

I am not using mypy; relying upon built-in type definitions in python. Is there --disallow-any-expr for built-in python type hinting ?

Comment: There is no built in type checker.  It sounds like your IDE is using one without you realizing it.  What IDE are you using?